# Quarkus Mutiny Multi Exception handling if no result

Tags: java, quarkus, mutiny

I need to throw a specific exception in the case if the multi stream doesn't return anything (empty / null in terms of multi stream result);

Here is my repository method:

```
return reactiveRepository.findAllById(idList);
```

which returns a

```
Multi<WhateverModel>
```

Is there a way for me to throw an exception if the above repository method doesn't return anything / null / empty stream?

I've tried filter, but it doesn't get invoked if the underlying repo method doesn't return a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the streams was empty on completion:

```java
stream.onCompletion().ifEmpty().continueWith("a", "b", "c");
```

That's probably what you need in your case.
You can also check that you have received items before a timeout:

```java
stream.ifNoItem().after(timeout)
    .recoverWithMulti(Multi.createFrom().items("a", "b", "c"))
```

However, not that `Multi` may not be what you are looking for here. It is often better to use `Uni<List<?>>` when dealing with a relational database, as their protocol does not support streaming, and, basically, it requires emulating streams in the application by keeping a connection opened.

Comment: Thank you Clement! I am not using a RDB but mongo. Is Multi still a good choice?

Comment: Ah sorry. Yes, Mongo is better. Streams are implemented using batches. It's not ideal (it keeps the connection open) but it is "less bad" than with most relational databases.